# AutoMapper - Map value if it's valid type

Tags: c#, automapper

These are my mapping classes:

```cs
class X
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
}

class Y
{
    public bool? BoolValue {get; set;}
    public DateTime? DateTimeValue {get; set;}
    public int? IntValue {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I want to map `X` to `Y`, and convert `X.Value` to the proper type:

```cs
CreateMap<X, Y>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BoolValue, op => op.MapFrom(src => bool.TryParse(src.Value, out bool res) ? src.Value : null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTimeValue, op => op.MapFrom(src => DateTime.TryParse(src.Value, out DateTime res) ? src.Value : null))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IntValue, op => op.MapFrom(src => int.TryParse(src.Value, out int res) ? src.Value : null))
    .ForAllOtherMembers(dest => dest.Ignore());
```

- If `X.Value` is `"true"`, then `Y.BoolValue` should be set to
  `true`, `Y.DateTimeValue` and `Y.IntValue` should be set to `null`
- If `X.Value` is `"2022.07.05"`, then `Y.DateTimeValue` should be set to `new DateTime(2022, 07, 05)`, `Y.BoolValue` and `Y.IntValue` should be set to `null`
- If `X.Value` is `"5"`, then `Y.IntValue` should be set to `5`, `Y.DateTimeValue` and `Y.BoolValue` should be set to `null`

I am getting an error:

> An expression tree may not contain an out argument variable declaration in `bool x`, `DatTime res`, `int res`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1**: Use `Func` delegate as replacement for the lambda expression.

```cs
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(ctx => {
    ctx.CreateMap<X, Y>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.BoolValue, op => op.MapFrom((X src, Y dest) =>
            {
                return bool.TryParse(src.Value, out bool res) ? src.Value : null;
            }))

        .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTimeValue, op => op.MapFrom((X src, Y dest) => 
            {
                return DateTime.TryParse(src.Value, out DateTime res) ? src.Value : null;
            }))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IntValue, op => op.MapFrom((X src, Y dest) => 
            {
                return int.TryParse(src.Value, out int res) ? src.Value : null;
            }))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(dest => dest.Ignore());
});
```

Based from [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=resolveusing#resolveusing),

```cs
void MapFrom(Expression<Func<TSource, TDestination>> mappingExpression);
```

---

**Solution 2**: Can also work with [Custom Value Resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html).

```cs
MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(ctx => {       
    ctx.CreateMap<X, Y>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.BoolValue, op => op.MapFrom<CustomValueResolver<bool?>>())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.DateTimeValue, op => op.MapFrom<CustomValueResolver<DateTime?>>())
        .ForMember(dest => dest.IntValue, op => op.MapFrom<CustomValueResolver<int?>>())
        .ForAllOtherMembers(dest => dest.Ignore());
});
```

```
public class CustomValueResolver<T> : IValueResolver<X, Y, T?>
{
    public T? Resolve(X source, Y destination, T? member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {   
            Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
            T? safeValue = source.Value != null
                ? (T?)Convert.ChangeType(source.Value, type)
                : default;
                
            return safeValue;
        }
        catch
        {
            return default;
        }
    }                                                        
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Cntk70)

From @Lucian's suggestion, this part:

```cs
Type type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));
T? safeValue = source.Value != null
    ? (T?)Convert.ChangeType(source.Value, type)
    : default;
                
return safeValue;
```

can be simplified with AutoMapper:

```cs
return context.Mapper.Map<T>(source.Value);
```

Comment: You can replace the code inside the `try` with `context.Mapper.Map<T>(source.Value)`.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu for the suggestion, was overthink to use the Reflection to do.